# Animation slow down after updating from 4.1 to 5.0.1

Tags: assimp

After updating to assimp 5.0.1 from 4.1 I noticed that animations in my engine were running very slow. I'm loading assets from .fbx files. I proceeded to do some debugging and found that `aiScene->mAnimations[i]->mDuration` value is different for the same assets between versions 4.1 and 5.0.1 of assimp:

**4.1:**

[image]

**5.0.1**

[image]

So that would be `33.3333` times slower. I can of course account for this in engine, but was curious to know if this was done on purpose and if so what that purpose was (as I noticed in release logs that improvements were made to the fbx importer for this release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We made a lot of improvements in the FBX-animations. The time-scaling was also refactored by the developers of the Godot team. So right now the times for the 5.0.1 animations are correct in terms of the FBX-specification.

That is the reason for the changes in times to a much slower animation.